# getting this error in discord .js bot idk why and how to solve this and i dont know in which file this error is occuring

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

man i dont know how to solve this when i run my bot terminal throw this error and i am getting it for 4 days sometimes it works and sometimes it does not i dont know in which file this error is occuring please help me

i run the bot and i got this error idk why   ```node:internal/process/promises:289
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

Error [ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT]: Socket connection timeout
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:399:5)
at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1098:20)
at Timeout.internalConnectMultipleTimeout (node:net:1637:3)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:575:11)
at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7) {
code: 'ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}```

Comment: How are you running your code ? What context ? Are you hosting it on a server ? If you use a container or VM, have you checked if it has access to the internet ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is not your not a error of Discord.js its a Node.js Error.

please try a different version of Node.js it may fix it!